How to add taskbar on Debian?
I have installed Debian with GNOME. then added minimise and maximise buttons in settings but how to go about adding windows-like task bar at the bottom to see active windows without escaping to activities?
I have something similar to taskbar at the top but it show only currently used app.

There are a number of Debian desktop GUI environments, such as MATE, KDE, etc. Most have a traditional taskbar, except for GNOME.
In order to add a taskbar to GNOME, use an extension, such as Dash to Panel
However might one of the other desktop environments which have a taskbar be a better choice for you?
